Possible to convert csv to geojson with ogr2ogr without null geometry values?
I'm using ogr2ogr to convert some csv to geojson via the following method now, instead of with VRT files as I used to:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.geojson input.csv 
-oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=longitude -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=latitude 
-skipfailures -addfields

When coordinates are missing, I now get "geometry": null whereas before I used to get 0 values for lat and long within geometry. I can work with it, but is there any way to get the old behavior, or even empty values instead of null?
